# Docking of Command and Service module with Lunar module

Tags: apollo-program, docking

Is there any video available which is shot inside CSM during the process of docking with LM to pull it out of adapter?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

> [The second stage of the Transposition, Docking and Extraction task
>   begins with a glimpse of Earth as the CSM turns to face the LM, Eagle,
>   parked in the top of the S-IVB third stage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gNoDx2h2EMI)

The LM comes into view about 35 seconds into the clip

[From the Apollo 11 Flight Journal](https://www.history.nasa.gov/afj/ap11fj/videoindex.html) Apollo 11 - 16-mm magazine 1116-A

Answer (score 1):

[Several videos](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCnVYpEWcPdnotlCz7kriFxg) of the docking process were made [on the Apollo 11 flight](https://spaceflight.nasa.gov/gallery/video/apollo/apollo11/html/lunar_activities.html).

LEM undocking shot from the CSM:

Shot from the LEM of the CSM receding after undocking:

LEM approach:

which is continued in a different film showing the final approach:

[final approach video](https://spaceflight.nasa.gov/gallery/video/apollo/apollo11/mpg/apollo11_onbclip03.mpg)

Comment: Thank You so much. I searched for such videos, but somehow, I was unable to reach this site.