# Looking for Apollo 11 powered descent video

Tags: apollo-program, apollo-11, video

At a science museum I visited on my 2018 fall vacation (I think it was the Chicago MSI), I saw a video loop that looked and sounded very much like part of the moon landing multimedia show at the Kennedy Space Center's Apollo/Saturn V Center. Both the video I saw this past fall, and the multimedia show, made a point of Armstrong having to take full manual control to avoid a boulder field. And while my memory could be playing tricks on me, the narration and music sounded very much like what I remember from my last visit to KSC.

Is this part of a commercially available DVD? Or something downloadable at a reasonable resolution?

I know it's definitely NOT Bill Gibson and Barry Coe's classic *Footprints on the Moon*; I have that on DVD; the narrator on the museum video was definitely neither Wernher von Braun (as himself) nor Pierre Jalbert (as Jules Verne), and the music on the museum video was definitely NOT Philip Moody's *Laguna Concerto*.

Failing that, I'm looking for any DVD or downloadable video that has good, but unadorned, coverage of the powered descent, and doesn't have some weird oblique letterbox, or a split-screen with a series of Lunar Orbiter stills. Coverage of EVA highlights would of course be a plus.

I'm not, for my immediate needs, interested in the transposition-and-docking video, and I've looked over the Apollo 11 Flight Journal index page, and at the videos that looked the most promising. It seems like there's a dearth of powered descent material among what's been posted online.

I'm honestly not sure what Mr. Neff's oblique letterbox is all about, either. (And yes, I'm aware that it's shot out a triangular window.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docking of Comand and servivice module with Lunar module](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/33313/docking-of-comand-and-servivice-module-with-lunar-module)

Comment: The linked question has links to 2 sites that contain all video shot during the Apollo missions, in unedited form (so no outsider commentary or music, just the comms between the astronauts an Houston).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure it's the video I remember seeing in museums, but if it isn't, it's definitely close enough for jazz:

It's called "Seventeen Seconds of Fuel Remained," and it appears to be an official NASA video (if so, then it's Public Domain by definition), and I found something that could give it to me as an MP4 file.

The narrator appears to be the Capcom on duty during Powered Descent (Charlie Duke, if I'm not mistaken, although he's the one person to appear on-camera without a title card identifying him); Gene Kranz, Neil Armstrong, and Buzz Armstrong also appear as onscreen narrators.

And it's good enough that I choked up from "Contact light" all the way to "You got a bunch of guys about to turn blue. We're breathing again."

Comment: I get choked up at the same point. 

Answer (score 2):

There is a fifteen minute video of the descent from lunar orbit to the surface here: [Apollo 11 landing from PDI to Touchdown](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RONIax0_1ec)

And a full list of the Apollo 11 movie footage at the [Apollo 11 Flight Journal](https://www.history.nasa.gov/afj/ap11fj/videoindex.html) site

Comment: Unfortunately, YouTube, by definition, is neither downloadable nor a commercially available DVD. And the powered descent video you cite specifically (BTW, the link is broken) has an oblique letterbox, and text commentary, both of which I'm specifically seeking to avoid.

Comment: @hbquikcomjamesl  - Fixed the link, sorry about that.  You can also download the quicktime .mov here:  https://history.nasa.gov/alsj/a11/A11Landing.mov  it doesn't have a text commentary.  If you like I'll burn it onto a DVD and sell it to you for $0.01?  Can't do anything about the aspect ratio though

Comment: YouTube is actually downloadable, using a number of web services and programs that are out there.

Comment: If I hadn't been told about services for downloading from YouTube, I never would have tried looking for one.